# Swift Completion Handler Not Called on Second Call to Function

Tags: swift, alamofire, completionhandler

I have a Swift function with a completion handler that I want to be called when a certain network request is done. The network request can be repeated based on if the server response says there is more data (`offset` is provided).

I initially call it like this:

```
func myMainFunction(){
  getTasks(project: project, paginationToken: nil) {
    print("This never fires...")
  }
}
```

And my `getTasks()` function is like this:

```
func getTasks(project: Project, paginationToken: String?, completion: @escaping () -> Void){
  var url = "..."
  if let token = paginationToken{
    url += "&offset=\(token)"
  }

  Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in  
    switch response.result {

    case .success(let value):
      let json = JSON(value)
      //...
      //Check for pagination
      let offset = json["next_page"]["offset"].stringValue
      if !offset.isEmpty{
        //Theres a pagination token available, go again!
        getTasks(project: project, paginationToken: offset){}
      }else{
        print("This prints to the log on the last run through")
        completion()
      }

    case .failure(let error):
      print("Task error: \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

If there is never an `offset` then the `completion()` handler works fine. But if `getTasks()` has to be called again, the completion handler is somehow invalidated and never returns to my original `myMainFunction()`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing empty closure if offset is not empty. You need to forward the completion param to getTasks again. Try this.

```
//...
if !offset.isEmpty {
    getTasks(project: project, paginationToken: offset, completion: completion)
}
//...
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So essentially it's keeping track of the original completion handler. I was removing it by passing a blank value on subsequent function calls. Makes sense. Thank you! :)